# $K_1\preccurlyeq K_2$ iff $C(K_1|_X,[0,1])\subseteq C(K_2|_X,[0,1])$ for any compactifications $K_1$ and $K_2$

Tags: general-topology

What shown below is a reference from "Elementos de Topología General" by Fidel Cassarubias Segura and Ángel Tamariz Mascarúa

> **Achtung!!!**
>
> If $(h,K)$ is compactification of $X$ it is common to identify $X$ with $h[X]$, since $h$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $h[X]$. So using this identification we can consider $X$ as a dense subspace of any its compactification $K$. So using this agreement if $(h,K)$ is a compactification of $X$ and if $p:K\rightarrow Y$ is a function, then we use $p|_X$ to indicate $p|_{h[X]}$, that is $p\circ h$. Therefore we indicate with
>   $$
> C(K|_X,[0,1]):=\{g|_X:g\in C(K,[0,1])\}
> $$
>   the set of all restrictions to $X$ of the continuous functions from $K$ to $[0,1]$.
>
> **Lemma**
>
> Let be $K$ a hausdorff compactification of $X$ and let be 
>   $$
> F:=\Delta_{f\in C(K,[0,1])}f:K\rightarrow[0,1]^{C(K,[0,1])}
> $$
>   the diagonal function of the collection $C(K,[0,1])$. So
>   $$
> (F|_{X},F[K])
> $$
>   is a hausdorff compactification of $X$ that is equivalent to $K$
>
> **Achtung!!!**
>
> If $K$ is a hausdorff compactification  of $X$ then we define the function $r:C(K,[0,1])\rightarrow C(K|_X,[0,1])$ defined as
>   $$
> r(g)=g|_X
> $$
>   for any $g\in C(K,[0,1])$: so using the density of $X$ in $K$ it is possible to prove that $r$ is a bijection. Now if $I$ and $J$ are two index collections such that $I\subseteq J$ and if $\mathfrak{X}_I=\{(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i): i\in I\}$ and $\mathfrak{X}_J=\{(X_j,\mathcal{T}_j): j\in J\}$ are two collections of topological spaces for which there exist an injection $\phi:I\rightarrow J$ such that $(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)=(X_{\phi(i)},\mathcal{T}_{\phi(i)})$ for any $i\in I$, we define the function 
>   $$
> \pi_I:\prod_{j\in J}X_j\rightarrow\prod_{i\in I}X_i
> $$
>   through the condition
>   $$
> \pi_I(f)=f|_I
> $$
>   for any $f\in\prod_{j\in J}X_j$: so using the universal mapping theorem for products it is possible to prove that $\pi_I$ is continuous. Then we name $\pi_I$ the projection of $\prod_{j\in J}X_j$ in $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$
>
> **Theorem**
>
> If $K_1$ and $K_2$ are two hausdorff compactifications of $X$ then it results that $K_1\preccurlyeq K_2$ if and only if it results that $C(K_1|_X[0,1])\subseteq C(K_2|_X,[0,1])$.
>
> *Proof*.
>
> 1. We suppose that $K_1\preccurlyeq K_2$, thus there exist a continuous function $p:K_2\rightarrow K_1$ such that $p|_X=id_X$. So if $f\in C(K_1|_X,[0,1])$ then there exist $f^*\in C(K_1,[0,1])$ that extend $f$ to $K_1$. So it is easy to verify that 
>      $$
>    g^*=f^*\circ p:K_2\rightarrow [0,1]
>    $$is a continuous extension of $f$ to $K_2$, thus we can claim that $f\in C(K_2|_X,[0,1])$.
> 2. So now we suppose that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are two compactifications of $X$ such that $C(K_1|_X,[0,1])\subseteq C(K_2|_X,[0,1])$ and we prove that $K_1\preccurlyeq K_2$. So let be
>      $$
>    F_1:=\Delta_{f\in C(K_1,[0,1])}f:K_1\rightarrow [0,1]^{C(K_1,[0,1])}
>    $$
>      and
>      $$
>    F_2:=\Delta_{g\in C(K_2,[0,1])}g:K_2\rightarrow[0,1]^{C(K_2,[0,1])}
>    $$
>      the diagonal functions of $C(K_1,[0,1])$ and $C(K_2,[0,1])$. Then for the previous lemma we know that $(F_1|_X,F_1[K_1])$ and $(F_2|_X,F_2[K_2])$ are two compactifications equivalent to $K_1$ and $K_2$ and so to prove the statement it is sufficient to discover a continuous function $p:F_2[K_2]\rightarrow F_1[K_1]$ such that $p\circ(F_2|_X)=F_1|_X$. So since the functions
>      $$
>    r_1:C(K_1,[0,1])\rightarrow C(K_1|_X,[0,1])
>    $$
>      and
>      $$
>    r_2:C(K_2,[0,1])\rightarrow C(K_2,[0,1])
>    $$
>      are bijections, we can respectively suppose that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are embeddings of $K_1$ in $[0,1]^{C(K_1|_X,[0,1])}$ and of $K_2$ in $C(K_2,[0,1])$. Now let be $\pi_{C(K_1|_X,[0,1])}$ the projection of $[0,1]^{C(K_2|_X,[0,1])}$ in $[0,1]^{C(K_1|_X,[0,1])}$ and we define $p=\pi_{C(K_1|_X,[0,1])}|_{F_2[K_2]}$. So it results that 
>      $$
>    (p(F_2(x)))(f)=(F_2(x)|_{C(K_1|_X,[0,1])})(f)=(F_2(x))(f)=f(x)=(F_1(x))(f)
>    $$
>      for any $x\in X$ and $f\in C(K_2|_X,[0,1])$, that is what we wanted.

For the sake of completeness to follow I put the original text of the proof: I hope mine was a good translation.

[image: -]

So I desire to discuss the inclusion
$$
C(K_1|_X,[0,1])\subseteq C(K_2|_X,[0,1])
$$
that I don't understand completely: from the proof of the point 1. of the theorem it seems to me that it means that there exist an injective function $\phi$ from $C(K_1|_X,[0,1])$ to $C(K_2|_X,[0,1])$; is this could be true? Then it seems to me that at the end of the proof there is a typo that I corrected in the traslation: is my revision correct?

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma In the photo at the end there is written $(p(F_1(x)))_f=(F_1(x))_f=f(x)=(F_2(x)))_f$ but it should be $(p(F_2(x)))_f=(F_2(x))_f=f(x)=(F_1(x)))_f$. Then I reworked the notation, making it more explicity: is my revision correct?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The lemma 7.42 is the lemma that I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Anyway [here](http://lya.fciencias.unam.mx/tamariz/notas/LibroCasarrubiasTamariz.pdf) you can download the book.

Comment: I see; a pretty trivial lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion $C(K_1\restriction X, [0,1]) \subseteq C(K_1\restriction X, [0,1])$ can be seen literally, if we unwind the homeomorphisms.

Suppose we have $p: K_2 \to K_1$ with $p \circ h_2 = h_1$ from $(h_1, K_1) \preceq (h_2, K_2)$. If $g \in C(K_1\restriction X, [0,1])$ this means that $g : X \to [0,1]$ is continuous and there is a continuous $\overline{g}: K_1 \to [0,1]$ such that $\overline{g} \circ h_1 = g$; i.e. $\overline{g}$ is an "extension" of $g$ modulo $h_1$, as it were. But then we can define $\overline{g'}: K_2 \to [0,1]$ by $\overline{g} \circ p$ (also continuous) and then

$$\overline{g'} \circ h_2 = (\overline{g} \circ p) \circ h_2 = \overline{g} \circ (p \circ h_2) = \overline{g} \circ h_1 = g$$ so that indeed (via the same convention/identification as before) $g \in C(K_2\restriction X, [0,1])$, so a literal inclusion, not just an injective map.

It seems to me, optically at least, that the diagram suggests we indeed need to consider the composition $p \circ (F_2\restriction X)$, but I have to check more carefully when I have more time tomorrow. It's a bit of a notational mess anyway, due to the extra homeomorphisms and hidden identifications.

Comment: Toonight I'll think to your answer: there is some thing I'd like to understand more exactly and so tomorrow I'll ask you clarification. Now it's late and so I'm going to bed: goodnight.

Comment: I tought about your answer: the proof is incontrovertible, or even exemplary. However I'm astonished that generally it could be $K_1 \neq K_2$: indeed if this is true then it's very unexpected that 
it could be $C (K_1 | _X, [0,1]) \subseteq C (K_2 | _X, [0,1])$, although it is even true that h1[X] and h2[X] are homeomorphic.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro It's not that unexpected: let $X=\Bbb R$, $K_1 = A(X)$, the Aleksandrov compactification, and $K_2 = [-\infty, +\infty]$, the ordered compactification. Then $f_1(x)= e^{-x^2}$ is in $C(K_1\restriction X, [0,1])$ and indeed also in $C(K_2\restriction X, [0,1])$, but $f(x)= \frac{\pi}{2}\arctan(x)$ from $X$ to $[0,1]$ is in $C(K_2\restriction X, [0,1])$ but not in $C(K_1\restriction X, [0,1])$, so the inclusion is strict. The map $p$ that maps $\{-\infty, \infty\}$ to $\infty \in A(X)$ witnesses that $K_1 \preceq K_2$, indeed.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems to me that the rank of $f(x)=\frac{\pi}2\text{arctan}(x)$ is not in $[0,1]$: perhaps do I make a mistake? Then if I understand to be more exactly is it $K_1=\Bbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I meant the factor $\frac{2}{\pi}$ so that we can extend by $-1$ and $1$. Your assertion about $K_1$ is indeed meant as such, so identity embedding for simplicity.