# How to make $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ using the Alexandroff compactification

Tags: general-topology

**Lemma**

Let be $(X,\le)$ an ordered set and let be $\infty\notin X$. So we define a new order $\preccurlyeq$ in $X^\infty:=X\cup\{\infty\}$ such that correspond to $\le$ in $X\subseteq X^\infty$: so for any $x_1,x_2\in X^\infty$ we define $x_1\preccurlyeq x_2$ iff $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $x_1\le x_2$ or if $x_2=\infty$ (or else $x_1=\infty$: so it is easy to show that $(X^\infty,\preccurlyeq)$ is an order relation in $X^\infty$ such that correspond to $X$ for any $x_1,x_2\in X\subseteq X^\infty$.

So using the above lemma we can add to $\Bbb{R}$ the points $\infty$ and $-\infty$ and so we can order $\overline{\Bbb{R}}:=\Bbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$ so that for any $x\in\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ it results that $-\infty\le x\le\infty$.

Then if $+$ and $\cdot$ are the usual sum and product in $\Bbb{R}$, for any $x\in \Bbb R$ we define
$$
\begin{align}
\infty+x &= \infty \\
-\infty+x &= -\infty \\
\infty+\infty &= \infty \\
-\infty-\infty &= -\infty \\
\infty-\infty=0\\
\frac{x}\infty &= 0 =\frac{x}{-\infty}\\
\frac{\infty}\infty=1\\
\frac{\infty}{-\infty}=-1=\frac{-\infty}\infty
\end{align}
$$
and for $\infty\ge x>0> y\ge -\infty$,
$$\begin{align}
x\cdot\infty &= \infty \\
x\cdot(-\infty) &= -\infty \\
y\cdot\infty &= -\infty \\
y\cdot(-\infty) &= \infty \\
0\cdot\infty &=0 = 0\cdot(-\infty).\\
\end{align}
$$
then we impose that the arithmetic of $\infty$ and $-\infty$ has all properties of arithmetic of usual real arithmetic.

So I asked to me if using two times the one-point compactification I can define on $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ the usual topology that we all know: so could someone show to me how formally to do this, please?

As reference [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3584697/how-prove-that-mathcalt-infty-mathcalt-cup-ux-setminus-u-is-compact-i) is defined the one-point compactification.

Comment: You can't get all properties of arithmetic for $\pm\infty$ with those definitions, as that leads to contradictions. For example: $\infty = \infty + 0 = \infty + (\infty-\infty) = (\infty + \infty) - \infty = \infty - \infty = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a specific construction for ordered spaces. There is a maximal one, called the Nachbin compactification (mentioned in [this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume11_4/109140.pdf) and its references, aka the Wallman ordered compactification). For $\Bbb R$ this is $\overline{\Bbb R}$.

This Nachbin compactification is only equal to the Aleksandrov compactification for specific ordered spaces, like $[0,\infty)$ e.g.

Comment: Okay, so I can't use the Aleksandrov compactification to make $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$, right? So I must use the Nachibin or Wallam compactification, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yes, one works for all locally compact Hausdorff spaces, the other for all ordered spaces. You’re preserving an ordered structure here and Akeksandrov usually doesn’t do that.

Comment: Okay. I understood: so in the article that you indicate there is explained the Nachbin compactification?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro the Walkman ordered compactification is, I think.  But there are references to it.

Comment: Okay, thanks too much.

Comment: When for you it is possible (I don't want disturb you), could you help me to understand what is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3610986/k-1-preccurlyeq-k-2-iff-ck-1-x-0-1-subseteq-ck-2-x-0-1-for-any-com) explained?

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic has little to do with this. You could consider $[0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and do its Aleksandrov compactification, which is obviously homeomorphic to $[0,\infty]\subset\bar{\mathbb{R}}$; similarly, $[-\infty,0]$ is the Aleksandrov compactification of $(-\infty,0]$. Now glue the two at $0$.

What's this “glueing”? The full space is $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=[-\infty,0]\cup[0,\infty]$. Points different from $0$ have as a basis of neighborhoods the neighborhoods they have in the subspace they sit in. As neighborhoods of $0$, take the sets $U_-\cup U_+$, where $U_-$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $[-\infty,0]$ and $U_+$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $[0,\infty]$.

This coincides with the usual (order) topology on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: So when I glue $[-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty]$ I must define the topological disjoint sum on $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$?

Comment: However $[-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty]$ are not disjoint.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Did I say they are? You have to glue them at $0$.

Comment: Okay, so when I glue them which is the topology defined on $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro The usual topology on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, of course.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro the quotient topology, which in this case is actually the order topology on $\overline{\Bbb R}$. But that is more of a happy coincidence.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, the structure of $\mathbb{R}$, in particular the *total* order, has a big role here,